# Anisble: get dynamic register from with_items

Tags: ansible, yaml

I've tried to create a register using `with_items` that can dynamically change with any added item.

```
- name: Set Openfile for specific user in /etc/security/limits.d/{{ user }}
  copy:
    dest: /etc/security/limits.d/"{{ item }}"
    content: |
      "{{ item }}"  - nofile 128000
      "{{ item }}"  - nproc  65536
  with_items:
    - kube
  register: ?
```

In the code above, I wanted to create a file in /etc/security/limits.d/{{user in with_items}}  and store that value in register. So in this case, value in item will be 'kube'.

```
- name: set permission and change owner of /etc/security/limits.d/{{ user }}
  file:
    path: /etc/security/limits.d/"{{ user }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

Later, I want to change the directory permissions I've created so it will be `/etc/security/limits.d/kube`

How can I specify path in `file` module from the earlier register got from `with_items` in the `copy` module above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  - name: Set Openfile for specific user in /etc/security/limits.d/{{ user }}
    copy:
            dest: "/etc/security/limits.d/{{ item }}"
            content: |
                    "{{ item }}"  - nofile 128000
                    "{{ item }}"  - nproc  65536
    with_items:
            - kube
    register: output

  - debug:
            msg: "{{item.item}}"
    loop: "{{output.results}}"
    loop_control:
            label: "{{item.item}}"

  - name: set permission and change owner of /etc/security/limits.d/{{ user }}
    file:
            path: "/etc/security/limits.d/{{ item.item }}"
            owner: root
            group: root
            mode: '0644'
    with_items:
            "{{output.results}}"
```

Make sure to run this with **become: yes**. we are storing the output in the "output variable". if there are multiple values in with items. it will store the multiple items output in the output variable(output.results). the output.results was giving the complex data structure output. so i have use loop_control(lable) to limit the output. the item.item give the output kube.